# Neo4j MERGE with race conditions

Tags: neo4j, constraints, race-condition

I am trying to merge a relationship in which I expect NodeA to be always present and I MERGE NodeB with a relationship

> MATCH (a:NodeA {propA:foo}) WITH a MERGE (a)-[:Rel]-(b:NodeB
> {propB:bar})

I am expecting combination of propB and Rel with A to be unique but getting multiple PropB nodes due to race conditions. How can I specify a uniqueness constraint on NodeB to be propB plus existing Rel? Apart from adding a pointer to NodeA on NodeB, which would bloat my database and is against the basic philosophy of graph databases?

Comment: you could create a unique property for nodeB consisting of (foo-bar) concatenation and then apply a unique constraint on it

Comment: @TomažBratanič yes, that’s essentially the last sentence of my question. As I said, it would bloat the database.

Comment: why would it bloat the database? you only add one additional property to NodeB and that's it. nothing else

Comment: About 800,000 nodes and, say uuid (32 characters ). So 28.8 Mb. But isn’t that a violation of the basic philosophy of graphs that we don’t store pointers since there is already a record in the form of a relationship?

Comment: In fact, another 30 Mb or so for the larger index on foo-bar instead of just bar.

Comment: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/ it seems there is no other way if you are dealing with concurrent updates

Comment: Perhaps I can use transaction in Neo4j? I am using neomodel driver, and it has this to say about wrapping an operation in transaction- https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transactions.html

Comment: Tomaz, do you think doing this in two steps 1) MATCH the whole pattern 1) Check the result and if empty list, CREATE NodeB would be a better approach? Speed is only a consideration at the Read part of CRUD for me.

Comment: I ended up adding the extra property. There was no other way to tackle the concurrency related issues!

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into multiple merge statements:

```
MATCH (a:NodeA {propA:foo})
MERGE (b:NodeB {propB:bar})
MERGE (a)-[:REL]->(b)
```

This should ensure that `a` exists or the query is no-op,  that `b` is created or found if it exists with `b.probB=bar` and then a single relationship with the type `:REL` is created between them.

Comment: This won’t work for me Simon, because NodeB doesn’t have unique propB. It is only unique in combination with its relationship with a NodeA. Think of NodeA as students and NodeB as ReportCards in this example https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-how-merge-works/

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. So you want to create the node and the relationship when neither exists and otherwise do nothing?

Comment: More or less. Actually, if a NodeB with propB=bar and with rel to NodeA with propA=foo exists, I will SET some other props (non-key) on NodeB